# Why function __construct is not working in PHP?

Tags: php, mysqli

Can someone explain

Why this did not works ?

```
<?php
class category
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "whatever");
    }

    function show_all()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT id_kategori, nama_kategori FROM kategori";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $cat);
        while($stmt->fetch())
        {
            echo "<td>$id</td>";
            echo "<td>$cat</td>";
            echo "<td>Update</td>";
            echo "<td>Delete</td>";
        };
        $stmt->close();
    }

}
?>
```

But this works ?

```
<?php
class category
{

    function show_all()
    {
        $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "whatever");
        $sql = "SELECT id_kategori, nama_kategori FROM kategori";
        $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $cat);
        while($stmt->fetch())
        {
            echo "<td>$id</td>";
            echo "<td>$cat</td>";
            echo "<td>Update</td>";
            echo "<td>Delete</td>";
        };
        $stmt->close();
    }

}
?>
```

Without construct, it works, with construct it's don't.

Can somebody show me, tell me, teach me how to include sql connection in a construct the right way ? I'm still new and learning by the way.

Comment: Probably because it already is a construct http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: While this is technically correct, the OP should know why specifically scoping variables is important as it appears they want to learn how to construct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of scoping. The `$con` variable should be defined to be used in the class exclusively rather than just locally inside the `__construct`.

When you define `$con` inside the `__construct` you are scoping this to be locally used inside the function `__construct` rather than in the class itself

Consider the following code

```
<?php
class category
{
    private $con;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "whatever");
    }

    function show_all()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT id_kategori, nama_kategori FROM kategori";
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $cat);
        while($stmt->fetch())
        {
            echo "<td>$id</td>";
            echo "<td>$cat</td>";
            echo "<td>Update</td>";
            echo "<td>Delete</td>";
        };
        $stmt->close();
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: Adding "this" give me error result

Notice: Undefined variable: con in C:\xampp\htdocs\whatever\login\admin\sql\category.php on line 6

Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in C:\xampp\htdocs\whatever\login\admin\sql\category.php on line 6

:(

Comment: Please see the full code where I define the the variable as private in the class

Comment: Wait, it's working after I copy paste them all :D many thnx :D

Comment: Keep this in mind, that if you extend this class and want to alter $con, change the scope from private to protected. Happy programming!

Comment: These codes are on my mind but I can't answer this because it is not tested. LOL. But +1 for good answer.

Answer (score 2):

$con is not a variable accessible in the class above: Try this:

```
<?php
class category
{

    private $con = NULL;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "whatever");
    }

    function show_all()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT id_kategori, nama_kategori FROM kategori";
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $cat);
        while($stmt->fetch())
        {
            echo "<td>$id</td>";
            echo "<td>$cat</td>";
            echo "<td>Update</td>";
            echo "<td>Delete</td>";
        };
        $stmt->close();
    }

}
?>
```

and look at documentation here:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php
and look up php scope:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Also if you are having questions always add this to your code: 
This would have told you the variable is undefined:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```